# How to deal with staticfiles module in an old version of django?

Tags: python, django, django-ckeditor

I want to deploy my app developed with `django 1.2.5` and I have a list of required packages, I have installed them and when I launch `http://localhost:8000` I get the following error:

```
from ckeditor.widgets import CKEditorWidget
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\ckeditor\widgets.py", line 4, in <module>
ImportError: No module named staticfiles.templatetags.staticfiles
```

I have installed a package called: `django-ckeditor 4.4.8` and it seems to be the root cause, I have seen the `ckeditor\widgets.py` file and trying to modify it but no chance (because of compilation in an egg file):

```
#ckeditor\widgets.py

from django.contrib.staticfiles.templatetags.staticfiles import static
    ...
        try:
            js += (
                    static('ckeditor/ckeditor/ckeditor.js'),
                    static('ckeditor/ckeditor-init.js'),
                    )
```

any workaround for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

**Firstly, you should really upgrade your app to a later version of Django. Django 1.2 is over 5 years old and has not received security updates for years.**

It looks like the line that is causing you problems has been [reverted in master](https://github.com/django-ckeditor/django-ckeditor/commit/84798109a7707e43220b2799f9ea0375123ae890). So you could try the previous version 4.4.7 or wait for the next release.

Comment: actually, that's the point but i should run it in my local environnment first